# Is the usage of among in "Some philosophers are addressed, among who Deleuze, Derrida,..." right?

Tags: phrases

I would like to know whether my usage of *among* in the following sentence is correct or not:

> Thus, a dialogue is developed with some philosophers who discuss and unfold the concept of ‘being’, among who, Deleuze, Nietzsche and Foucault.

Comment: I would suggest "'being'; among them are Deleuze, . . ." or "'being,' among whom are Deleuze, . . ." or "'being,' including Deleuze, . . . ." In any case, "among" is a preposition, so "whom" is preferable to "who" as its object, in pretty much any context that is formal/academic enough to be dropping these names in.

Comment: I appreciate your answer, Brian Donovan. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Posting as a comment since I don't have an authority: my preferences in order are: (1) "... including Deleuze, ..." (2) "... among whom are Deleuze ..." (3) "among them Deleuze ...".

Comment: The sentence is OK (if elephantine) up to _'being',_. But next clause no verb.

Comment: Yes, I expected a verb after *Deleuze, Nietzsche and Foucault*. Otherwise "among who..." what?

Answer (score 1):

Starting off a pseudo-appositional clause of this type with a relative pronoun like *who(m)* creates a very strong expectation with the reader that there will be a **verb** in the clause. This expectation is not there (or is at least much less prominent) if you use a demonstrative pronoun instead:

> … philosophers who discuss and unfold the meaning of ‘being’—among them Deleuze, Nietzsche, and Foucault. *[fine with no verb]*
>
> … philosophers who discuss and unfold the meaning of ‘being’—among whom Deleuze, Nietzsche, and Foucault *[verb is expected here]*.

Since there is no meaningful verbal statement included in what you wish to say, the simplest way out is to simply use a verb that implies nothing but existence: *be*:

> … philosophers who discuss and unfold the meaning of ‘being’, among whom are Deleuze, Nietzsche, and Foucault.

Another choice, since an existential clause like this does (to my ear) end up sounding a bit inelegant, would be to simply say *among others*; or, if this is a formal, academic text, like an article, go all out for the fancy Latinate version instead:

> … philosophers who discuss and unfold the meaning of ‘being’—**among others**, Deleuze, Nietzsche, and Foucault.
>
> … philosophers who discuss and unfold the meaning of ‘being’—**inter alios**, Deleuze, Nietzsche, and Foucault.